# Prime number checker function is faulty

Tags: python, primes

I wrote a function to calculate whether or not a number is prime, but try as it might, it just seems unable to give the correct response. It also prints the n value that is being incremented. Here is the code for the function (in Python, by the way):

```
def isPrime(x):
    for n in range(1, x):
        print n
        if x % n == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

If I input

```
isPrime(17)
```

the function returns

```
1
False
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: definition of prime number is wrong

Comment: Just a side note: there are *loads* of ways to optimize a prime number checker, but a simple one is: just check up to the square root of x. So, add `from math import sqrt, floor` and then change your range to `range(2,floor(sqrt(x)))`

Comment: your original logic, as a pythonic one liner: `def isPrime(x): return x > 1 and all(x % n for n in xrange(2,x))`

Comment: related: [Why 1 is not considered to be a prime number?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/120/1665)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Every number is divisible by 1 and itself**. A prime number is a natural number that has no positive divisors *other* than 1 and itself. Therefore, if you start your for-loop with 1, **every** number `x` will pass the condition `x % 1 == 0` in the first iteration, returning `False`.

To fix it, you need to start your loop with 2 instead of 1. Also, as a side-note, you just need to loop from 2 to `sqrt(x)`, since if there exists a number `q > sqrt(x)` that divides `x`, then there must also be a number `p = x / q` which also divides `x`, and `p < sqrt(x)`.